# How to Remove a Field from a wxStatusBar

Tags: wxpython, field, statusbar

This may be obvious, but I'm missing it.  I'm working in wxpython.

I have a wxStatusBar with several fields (these fields have text as well as other widgets).  I need to be able to add and remove these fields throughout the app session.  Is there a way to remove fields from a statusbar, or do I just have to redraw it?  I think to do the latter I could use the SetFields() function, but I'm not quite sure what type of list to give SetFields()...the only example I've seen gives it a list of strings, but I have more than strings to pass it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the number of fields by calling `mystatusbar.SetFieldsCount(numfields)`.  Rescale them if desired with `.SetStatusWidths([list])`.  Change text at individual positions using `.SetStatusText('string', position)`.  If you have some control (e.g. a checkbox) hiding in a status bar section, you can move it to the spot given by `.GetFieldRect(position)`.  Call this on wx.EVT_SIZE or whenever you remove/eliminate stuff.

If you remove fields from somewhere other than the end (highest index), you'll have to manually shift your data first.  You mentioned you were using `.SetFields()`, just take the list you passed earlier and `.pop()` out the one you don't want.

Some repositioning code from wxPython demo:

```
# reposition the checkbox
def Reposition(self):
    rect = self.GetFieldRect(1) # the checkbox lives in the 2nd (index 1) slot
    self.cb.SetPosition((rect.x+2, rect.y+2))
    self.cb.SetSize((rect.width-4, rect.height-4))
    self.sizeChanged = False
```

Look in the [wxPython Demo app](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php) for some example code you can quickly hack up and run from within it.